# Allergic reactions to food

Tags: dogs

I just learned that my dog is allergic to Pinto beans, beef, milk and liver.  I am at a loss of what I can serve her to eat.  She has episodes of diarrhea.

Comment: you need to give more details where do you live the age-type of dog and how was the test done.

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE. :) Can you give us an idea of what you usually feed the dog (and her size, breed, etc)?

Answer (score 4):

"Pinto Beans, beef, milk, and liver" is a very short list, half of which is not truly species-appropriate anyway. There are myriad other options available, whether buying commercial dog foods or preparing your own. Chicken is the most obvious, but there are also foods using lamb, salmon, venison, and other protein sources. Take the initiative to read labels if you are purchasing commercial dog foods, and select an option that does not include the list of foods to which your dog is allergic.

Answer (score 0):

Look into what is called "limited ingredient" dog food.

These dog foods are specifically designed to contain as few different types of ingredients as possible, which makes it easier to identify each type of ingredient. Limited Ingredient food is made with allergens in mind, so it is more likely that you will find something compatible with particular diets.

It's important to understand that a fresh ingredient is completely different from a processed ingredient. For example, if your dog is allergic to foods with beef on the ingredients label, they will also be allergic to beef meal, beef trimmings, etc, because they would all be very similar. But, that your dog should be okay with a chunk of uncooked beef or even freshly cooked beef with nothing else added (say, you made it at home). This is because what your dog is actually allergic to is likely to be something involving the chemicals or production process of making dry dog food. (*)

(*) Please do not go to the grocery store and buy raw meat to feed your dog. These meats are graded to be safe for human consumption only after proper cooking at certain temperatures and may contain parasites and bacteria otherwise. If you wish to eat raw meat or feed your dog it, look for special meat that has been graded for raw consumption - it is pricier.